# Running RSelenium with Opera

Tags: r, selenium, opera, rselenium

I am trying to use RSelenium with Opera (Version 72). I already downloaded the current version of the opera drivers from https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases.

However, I am facing two problems which I did not figure out yet.

What`s the procedure for installing the opera drivers? I ran the .exe, but only some lines in the win console appeared.

What is the right code? My latest try is:

```
remDr = remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4444, browserName = "opera",extraCapabilities = list("opera.binary" = "C:[..]/operadriver.exe"))
(I also tried remDr = remoteDriver([...] /launch.exe"))
remDr$open()
```

In doing this, I got the response:

```
"Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4444: Connection refused"
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you try the other browsers?

Comment: Yes, I usually use Chrome and Firefox. However, in this case, only Opera helps in my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ Download the [opera driver](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases) and [Opera](https://www.opera.com/download) ]

*The download process also can be automated (however not posting it here)*

Then

```
se <- wdman::selenium(
  check = FALSE,
  jvmargs = list(
    opera =
      paste0(
        "-Dwebdriver.opera.driver=",
        normalizePath(
          "<give correct path>/operadriver.exe"
        )
      )
  ))

rd <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(browserName = "opera", port = 4567L)
rd$open()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: @adamsmith1989 if this is the correct answer kindly accept that  :-) Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

I found a work-around that works.

I first called:

```
selCommand=wdman::selenium(jvmargs = c("Dwebdriver.chrome.verboseLogging=true"), retcommand = TRUE)
cat(selCommand)
```

This gave me the path of the chromedriver.exe used by rsDriver (in my case C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\binman\binman_chromedriver\win32\87.0.4280.20\chromedriver.exe). Next, I downloaded the operadriver.exe from https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releas and copied it into this folder. Afterwards, I deleted the original chromedriver.exe and renamed the operadriver.exe into chromedriver.exe. Then I called:

```
rD=rsDriver(browser = c("chrome"))
remDr=remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4567L, browserName = "chrome")
remDr=rD$client
```

And it indeed it works as expected! Does someone has a more convenient method?